# From Euler forward method in to Euler backward.

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

I have a system of linear differential equations

$$y'=Ay+b,$$

where

```
A = [0 0 0 1;0 0 1 0;0 0 1 0;0 0 0 -1];
b = [0; 0; 1; 0];
y0 = [1; 0; 0; -2];
tinit = 0;
h = 0.1;
tFinal = 2;
```

Solving it with Euler forward, worked nicely by using $$y_{k+1}=y_k+hf(t_{k},y_k),$$

the functioncode is:

```
function yOut = eulerforward(F,t0,h,tFinal,y0)
    Y = y0;
    yOut = Y;
    for t = t0 : h : tFinal
            s = F(t,Y);
            Y = Y + h*s;
        yOut = [yOut Y];
    end
end
```

and finally

```
F = @(t,Y) A*Y + b;
K1 = eulerforward(F,tinit,h,tFinal,y0);
```

Now, Euler backward is formulated by

$$y_{k+1}=y_k+hf(t_{k+1},y_{k+1}).$$

How can I modify my Euler forward code so that it uses the Euler backward method?

Is $s$ the only parameter that will change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using backward Euler you need to find the zero of $F(\mathbf{y})=\mathbf{y} - \mathbf{y_n} - kf(\mathbf{y})$, where $y_n$ is the solution at time $n$. Of course this zero is the next value of the solution.
Usually you need to solve a non-linear system, but if the problem is linear, then you have just to solve a linear system at every iteration (for example using $\verb|\|$ in Octave).

In this case $f(y)=Ay+b$, so the numerical scheme is:

$y_{n+1}=y_n + k(Ay_{n+1} + b)$, so we have $(I-kA)\cdot y_{n+1}=y_n + kb$, with the initial value $y_0$ given.

If you want to use a function called "backward Euler" you will need to use Newton's method.

Here's a runable MatLab code for your specific problem.

```
y0=[1; 0; 0; -2];
tinit = 0;
h = 0.1;  
tFinal = 2;
ts=tFinal/h; %timesteps


%matrix
A = [0 0 0 1;0 0 1 0;0 0 1 0;0 0 0 -1];
b = [0; 0; 1; 0];

y=NaN(4,ts+1);
b = [0; 0; 1; 0];
y(:,1)=y0;
%loop
for n=1:ts
    y(:,n+1)=(eye(4)-h*A)\(y(:,n)+h*b);   
end
t=linspace(tinit,tFinal,ts+1);
plot(t,y(1,:),'b-o',t,y(2,:),'r-o',t,y(3,:),'g-o',t,y(4,:),'k-o')
legend('first','second','third','fourth equation')
```

Comment: What is the NaN function?

Comment: So let's proceed with your code. Say I now want to solve the same differential equation but instead using the trapezoid method: $$y_{k+1}=y_k+\frac{h}{2}(f(t_k,y_k)+f(t_{k+1},y_{k+1})),$$ how would your code change? I don't really see why the NaN is used for. Im trying to use this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/38865/how-do-i-use-matlab-to-solve-an-euler-backward-problem-for-a-differential-equati link to rewrite my ODE's but I feel like mine is written quite differently.

Comment: I think I'm confused with the notations. I'm using $t_k$ somewhere, you are using bold letters sometimes and sometimes not. How did you go from $F(\mathbf{y})=\mathbf{y} - \mathbf{y_n} - kf(\mathbf{y})$  to $y_{n+1}=y_n + k(Ay_{n+1} + b)$ and then finally to $(I-kA)\cdot y_{n+1}=y_n + kb$ ?

Comment: Thank you for the help. I understood about everything (except the NaN thing) after staring at this for a few hours. Can you please explain why you used the NaN function?

Comment: You're right about the fact that my notations are not so good. Anyway: I just initialized the matrix which contains every component of the solution.

Comment: To go from $F(\mathbf{y})$ to $y_{n+1}=y_n + k(Ay_{n+1} + b)$ I just wrote $F(\mathbf{y})=0$ and substitute $f(\mathbf{y})$ with  $A_y + b$. The last equality is trivial: I need to find an expression for $y_{n+1}$ which depends only on $y_n$

Comment: You can apply trapezoidal rule with the same arguments. Hints: write down explicitly who is $F(\mathbf{y})=\vec{0}$. Since it's a linear equation, you'll have to solve linear systems.

Comment: Yes I figured everything out yesterday, just took some time. However, I still can't figure out what the purpose of the NaN is?

Comment: Ah, okay I see now why the NaN is used! Thanks a lot Vob, you're great!

Comment: It could help you to see if your code has some mistakes :). Hi